# Is there any way to disable the UTF-8 encoding of the subject line?

Tags: email, character-encoding, utf

I am using `mail` command to send a simple mail to my account. I receive the email properly. Then i try to extend it and try sending it to `sms-gateway` and receive an sms on the required mobile number. The message body appears fine but the `subject` header is `utf-8 encoded(?=utf-8?B?some-encoded-content?=)`.

I would like to know if there is any way to disable the subject line encoding while sending the mail.

Comment: It is a well know standard and all client email should be able to interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

No, all non-ASCII characters in an email must be encoded in some form or another, and the subject line must be [MIME-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) (what you're seeing is MIME encoding, not "UTF-8"). You must properly parse and decode the email, including its subject line.

Comment: If both ends support the [ESMTP UTF-8 extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_SMTP#SMTPUTF8) this is no longer true, but that's a big if. Anyway, the real conclusion here is that your SMS gateway is broken if it cannot handle MIME correctly.